# JSON server and custom routes

Tags: json, routes, json-server

I'm using JSON server. If I initialize it with `npx json-server --watch database.json --port 5000` and then open `http://localhost:5000/items` I can see all the items. If I go to `http://localhost:5000/items/1` I have only one item. My question is - how can I change single item route so I get the first item by entering `http://localhost:5000/items/myCustomId1`? In other words, how can I replace `id` with `customId`?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "customId": "myCustomId1",
      "name": "Item 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "customId": "myCustomId2",
      "name": "Item 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should ask it not here,but API server administrator if you don't have list of APIs

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong tool for the job. json-server is not a production ready API

Comment: There is no administrator. It's a dummy database for testing the frontend side in React application (simulating API call). Now I'm trying to figure out how to fetch a single product with a custom id as a query parametr.

Comment: You have to show the API code then

Comment: @Serge it's [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), an off-the-shelf open source API

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do here is using parameters handling for that request. For instance, you can do `http://localhost:5000/items?myCustomId=1` in your case. This will probably list all the items with customId of 1 instead of just 1 item (since customId is not unique in this case).